# Probability of colission when hash is half the size of data?

Tags: string, hashing

If i had a password of 100 bits, and hashed it with a hash function that returned a 50 bit key, now i brute force it until a get a string that produces a matching hash, is there now a 50% chance that the string i have produced with brute-force is not the origional password, but a string that produces a colission?

Answer (score 1):

No. It's much, *much* less than that. If we assume the hash function is perfect, there are 2^50 passwords that produce the same 50-bit hash.

Use simple numbers to make it clearer. Say you have 10^4 widgets (10,000) and you put them in 10^2 boxes (100). How many widgets are in the average box? Well, it's 10,000/100 or 100. So if you are looking for a particular widget and know only it's box, there's a 1 in 100 chance a randomly-selected widget from that box will be the right one.

Doing the math with your numbers gives a 1 in 2^50 chance.

Comment: Hmm, i see, but if i produced a hash of all the possible combinations of 100 bits and returned a 50bit key, then at least half of all the hashes returned must be a colission right? but i suppose this changes when there is only 1 specific string we are looking for :)

Comment: If the hash function is perfect, all the inputs will collide equally and each 50-bit hash will correspond to 2^50 possible 100-bit passwords. I'm not sure where you keep getting "half" from.